# How do I create a contact with LDAP and have it show up in the GAL?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I can create a contact that is not mail enabled, but how do I mail enable it and have it show up in the Global Address List?

Is it just a matter of setting more attributes or is there something more involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the attributes mailNickname,targetaddress and showinaddressbook the mail enabled extended attributes were automatically added.

After proper cache cycling the contacts showed properly in Outlook.

Further I had to add: msExchPoliciesExcluded to keep the email address on the contacts from being recast as our main domain.

After that everything is working great.